# Creating Java web service client

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

i'm trying to study about how to access external web services.
I have created a Web Service Client in eclipse for the following web service:

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=9&CATID=2

And I tried to access this web service with the next code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        StockQuoteLocator locator = new StockQuoteLocator();
        locator.setEndpointAddress("StockQuoteSoap", "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx");
        StockQuoteSoapStub stock = new StockQuoteSoapStub(locator);
        System.out.println(stock.getQuote("TEVA"));         
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

But i'm keep getting the error:

```
06/02/2012 11:29:51 org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.NoEndpoint
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: No endpoint
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}exceptionName:org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:No endpoint
at NET.webserviceX.www.StockQuoteSoapStub.getQuote(StockQuoteSoapStub.java:93)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:MICHALEDR-DTW7

No endpoint
    at NET.webserviceX.www.StockQuoteSoapStub.getQuote(StockQuoteSoapStub.java:93)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Can you please help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says that those classes are missing in your classpath.

Add [activation.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.activation.DataHandler) and [javamail.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart) to your classpath.

Comment: This is not the answer. There are two issues above, you're only fixing the warnings, not the error.